# Incorrect path to Wikipedia favicon in chat onebox

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

In Stack Exchange Chat, the wikipedia icon does not show up correctly in the onebox:

[image: wikipedia onebox]

I checked the code on the Stack Exchange chat page and it points to [`//en.wikipedia.org/favicon.ico`](//en.wikipedia.org/favicon.ico). This doesn't return a 404, but it also doesn't return a favicon image. It just returns an empty response body with http status code `200 OK`.

The correct path is [`//en.wikipedia.org/static/favicon/wikipedia.ico`](//en.wikipedia.org/static/favicon/wikipedia.ico):

[image: wikipedia icon]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [image]

Comment: FHRS - awesome!

Comment: While at it, looks like more and more links points to `/?title=[foo]` instead of `/wiki/[foo]` like it used to be, can the oneboxing please support the new format? e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat (not oneboxed) vs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat (onebox working)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Looks like that's an [alternative format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:URL#URLs_of_Wikipedia_pages) and `/wiki/` is still king. I'm okay with not writing a new regex to catch all `title` cases unless there's a strong demand and need for it. :) New feature request, perhaps?

Comment: hmm... thanks, will do if I won't forget. :)